# Does the Skyforge affect crafting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Skyforge, behind the Companion's base, seems a bit special. The Companions speak of it as if it had some magical powers, and built their base there because of it.

My question is: does the Skyforge grant any bonus to Smithing quality when you craft weapons or armor on it? For example, would a 100 AR Daedric Armor on a normal forge be a (for example) 110 AR piece when smithed on the Skyforge?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have yet to see or experience anything to suggest that it does actually improve the quality of items nor does it offer a "Fortify Smithing" bonus. However, it does have [some unique properties (spoiler)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyforge). Using smithing as much as I do I would love to be proven wrong though as I think it would add an interesting facet to the "profession".